# How to remove outliers from a dataset

Tags: r

I've got some multivariate data of beauty vs ages. The ages range from 20-40 at intervals of 2 (20, 22, 24....40), and for each record of data, they are given an age and a beauty rating from 1-5. When I do boxplots of this data (ages across the X-axis, beauty ratings across the Y-axis), there are some outliers plotted outside the whiskers of each box.

I want to remove these outliers from the data frame itself, but I'm not sure how R calculates outliers for its box plots. Below is an example of what my data might look like.
[image]

Comment: The `boxplot` function returns the outliers (among other statistics) invisibly.  Try `foo <- boxplot(...); foo` and read `?boxplot` to understand the output.

Comment: Relevant: http://davidmlane.com/ben/outlier.gif

Comment: Can you send a link to the data?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

OK, you should apply something like this to your dataset. Do not replace & save or you'll destroy your data! And, btw, you should (almost) never remove outliers from your data:

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  y
}
```

To see it in action:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
x <- c(-10, x, 10)
y <- remove_outliers(x)
## png()
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
boxplot(x)
boxplot(y)
## dev.off()
```

And once again, you should never do this on your own, outliers are just meant to be! =)

**EDIT:** I added `na.rm = TRUE` as default.

**EDIT2:** Removed `quantile` function, added subscripting, hence made the function faster! =)

[image]

Comment: OK, I'm missing something here. You want to remove outliers from data, so you can plot them with `boxplot`. That's manageable, and you should mark @Prasad's answer then, since answered your question. If you want to exclude outliers by using "outlier rule" `q +/- (1.5 * H)`, hence run some analysis, then use this function. BTW, I did this from scratch, w/o Googling, so there's a chance that I've reenvented the wheel with this function of mine...

Comment: To be even more general, make the `1.5` an arg of the function, with a default. And allow separate lower and upper ranges: `c(-1.5,+1.5)`

Comment: "outliers are just meant to be"? Not necessarily. They may come from measure errors, and must be thoroughly reviewed. When the outlier is too big, it may mean something, or not so much. That's why (at least in biology) the median usually says more about a population than the mean.

Comment: Nice. How about replace IQR with SD? e.g., `H <- 8 * sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)`? Would this exclude values above or below 8 sd of mean?

Comment: indeed it would

Answer (score 166):

Nobody has posted the simplest answer:

```
x[!x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out]
```

Also see this: http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/01/how-to-label-all-the-outliers-in-a-boxplot/

Comment: Really elegant. Thanks. But need to be careful if distribution has more than one mode and outliers are indeed only few and scattered.

Comment: It would have been great if you were able to get index of them in a dataset. The way you are done will filter based on data value. If box plot is also doing grouping, not necessarily same data value will be outlier in each group

Comment: It's also important to mention that it does not change the dataset. This is just a filtering method. So if you intend to use the dataset without outliers assign it to a variable.

e.g. `result = x[!x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out]`

Comment: @adam please see my answer to address this issue below.

Comment: A question on boxplot.stats(): does anyone know how the function defines an outlier? E.g., based on a certain multiple of standard deviations from the mean?

Comment: @bt3 they are any values lying outside the whiskers; the whiskers by default are 1.5 times the size of the box; the box is basically defined by the first and third quartiles. see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.2/topics/boxplot.stats

Answer (score 32):

Use `outline = FALSE` as an option when you do the boxplot (read the help!).

```
> m <- c(rnorm(10),5,10)
> bp <- boxplot(m, outline = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: indeed, this will remove the outliers from the boxplot itself, but I want to remove the outliers from the data frame.

Comment: I see, then as @Joshua said you need to look at the data returned by the boxplot function (in particular the `out` and `group` items in the list).

Answer (score 17):

The boxplot function returns the values used to do the plotting (which is actually then done by bxp():

```
bstats <- boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray") 
#need to "waste" this plot
bstats$out <- NULL
bstats$group <- NULL
bxp(bstats)  # this will plot without any outlier points
```

I purposely did not answer the specific question because I consider it statistical malpractice to remove "outliers". I consider it acceptable practice to not plot them in a boxplot, but removing them just because they exceed some number of standard deviations or some number of inter-quartile widths is a systematic and unscientific mangling of the observational record.

Comment: Well, sidestepping the question without knowing why the question was asked is not a good practice either. Yes, it is not good to remove 'outliers' from the data but sometimes you need the data without outliers for specific tasks. In an statistics assignment I had recently, we had to visualise a set without its outliers to determine the best regression model to use for the data. So there!

Comment: I'm not considering the advice you may have gotten in this regard to "determine the best regression model" to be particularly persuasive. Instead, if you needed to remove outliers for that vaguely stated purpose, then I think it reflects poorly on the persons who advised it rather than being evidence of invalidity of my position.

Comment: I guess its legit when you know you're removing "noise". especially in physiological data.

Comment: Yes. If you have good reason to believe that a separate process creates the signal, it is justification for removal from the data.

Answer (score 13):

I looked up for packages related to removing outliers, and found this package (surprisingly called "outliers"!): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/outliers.pdf

if you go through it you see different ways of removing outliers and among them I found `rm.outlier` most convenient one to use and as it says in the link above:
"If the outlier is detected and confirmed by statistical tests, this function can remove it or replace by
sample mean or median" and also here is the usage part from the same source:
"**Usage**

```
rm.outlier(x, fill = FALSE, median = FALSE, opposite = FALSE)
```

**Arguments** 
*x*  a dataset, most frequently a vector. If argument is a dataframe, then outlier is
removed from each column by sapply. The same behavior is applied by apply
when the matrix is given.
*fill*  If set to TRUE, the median or mean is placed instead of outlier. Otherwise, the
outlier(s) is/are simply removed.
*median*  If set to TRUE, median is used instead of mean in outlier replacement.
opposite if set to TRUE, gives opposite value (if largest value has maximum difference
from the mean, it gives smallest and vice versa)
"

Comment: This seems great, but if you have a time series column in your data frame, it changes the time series.

Answer (score 9):

```
x<-quantile(retentiondata$sum_dec_incr,c(0.01,0.99))
data_clean <- data[data$attribute >=x[1] & data$attribute<=x[2],]
```

I find this very easy to remove outliers. In the above example I am just extracting 2 percentile to 98 percentile of attribute values.

Answer (score 8):

Wouldn't:

```
z <- df[df$x > quantile(df$x, .25) - 1.5*IQR(df$x) & 
        df$x < quantile(df$x, .75) + 1.5*IQR(df$x), ] #rows
```

accomplish this task quite easily?

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @sefarkas' suggestion and using quantile as cut-offs, one could explore the following option:

```
newdata <- subset(mydata,!(mydata$var > quantile(mydata$var, probs=c(.01, .99))[2] | mydata$var < quantile(mydata$var, probs=c(.01, .99))[1]) )
```

This will remove the points points beyond the 99th quantile. Care should be taken like what aL3Xa was saying about keeping outliers. It should be removed only for getting an alternative conservative view of the data.

Comment: is it `0.91` or `0.99`? as in `mydata$var < quantile(mydata$var, probs=c(.01, .91))[1])` or `mydata$var < quantile(mydata$var, probs=c(.01, .99))[1])`

Comment: If you have a specific reason to use 91st percentile instead of 99th percentile, you can use it. It is only a heuristic

Answer (score 3):

#### 1 way to do that is

```
my.NEW.data.frame <- my.data.frame[-boxplot.stats(my.data.frame$my.column)$out, ]
```

#### or

```
my.high.value <- which(my.data.frame$age > 200 | my.data.frame$age < 0) 
my.NEW.data.frame <- my.data.frame[-my.high.value, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Outliers are quite similar to peaks, so a peak detector can be useful for identifying outliers. The method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data) has quite good performance using z-scores. The animation part way down the page illustrates the method signaling on outliers, or peaks.

Peaks are not always the same as outliers, but they're similar frequently.

An example is shown here:
This dataset is read from a sensor via serial communications. Occasional serial communication errors, sensor error or both lead to repeated, clearly erroneous data points. There is no statistical value in these point. They are arguably not outliers, they are errors. The z-score peak detector was able to signal on spurious data points and generated a clean resulting dataset: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Feed your variable in the function and save the o/p in the variable which would contain removed outliers

```
outliers<-function(variable){
    iqr<-IQR(variable)
    q1<-as.numeric(quantile(variable,0.25))
    q3<-as.numeric(quantile(variable,0.75))
    mild_low<-q1-(1.5*iqr)
    mild_high<-q3+(1.5*iqr)
    new_variable<-variable[variable>mild_low & variable<mild_high]
    return(new_variable)
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Refer to *[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*.

Answer (score 0):

It is more difficult to remove outliers with grouped data because there is a risk of removing data points that are considered outliers in one group but not in others.

Because no dataset is provided I assume that there is a dependent variable "attractiveness", and two independent variables "age" and "gender". The boxplot shown in the original post above is then created with `boxplot(dat$attractiveness ~ dat$gender + dat$age)`. To remove outliers you can use the following approach:

```
# Create a separate dataset for each group
group_data = split(dat, list(dat$age, dat$gender))

# Remove outliers from each dataset
group_data = lapply(group_data, function(x) {

  # Extract outlier values from boxplot
  outliers = boxplot.stats(x$attractiveness)$out

  # Remove outliers from data
  return(subset(x, !x$attractiveness %in% outliers))
})

# Combine datasets into a single dataset
dat = do.call(rbind, group_data)
```