# detecting outliers on wide data frame

Tags: r

x

```
Team Date       Score
A    1-1-2012   80
A    1-2-2012   90
A    1-3-2012   50
A    1-4-2012   40   
B    1-1-2012   100
B    1-2-2012   60
B    1-3-2012   30
B    1-4-2012   70
etc
```

I need to and can turn this data frame to wide data frame one row for each team with all the observations and dates as the heading:

xx

```
Team 1-1-2012 1-2-2012  1-3-2012 1-4-2012
A    80       90        50        40
B    100     60         30        70
```

I need to calculate the mean and sd for each row, which I can do:

xx

```
Team 1-1-2012 1-2-2012  1-3-2012 1-4-2012  mean   sd
A    80       90        50        40       75    20
B    100     60         30        70       55    10
```

Considering I have thousands of row in data frame xx. I would like to do calculation on each cell as this:

if abs(xx-Mean) > 3*SD, create a counter column name and increment the value. The idea is that compare each observation against the mean and sd, if each observation for a given team matches this - abs(xx-Mean) > 3*SD, increment the counter. After checking each cell, I would like to look at each counter for each team and get the top ten high team that has the highest counter value. Basically I am trying to detect the most outliers. Once I get the top 10 team names, I would like to graph their time series data on data frame x.

I hope I am not making this more complicated than it should be. Not sure, R already has function to do calculations on each cell. Any ideas how to accomplish this is appreciated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `long-format`, `data.table` approach

```
DT <- read.table( 'clipboard', header = T)
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DT)
DT[, mean.score := mean(Score), by = Team]
##    Team     Date Score mean.score
## 1:    A 1-1-2012    80         65
## 2:    A 1-2-2012    90         65
## 3:    A 1-3-2012    50         65
## 4:    A 1-4-2012    40         65
## 5:    B 1-1-2012   100         65
## 6:    B 1-2-2012    60         65
## 7:    B 1-3-2012    30         65
## 8:    B 1-4-2012    70         65
DT[, sd.score := sd(Score), by = Team]
##    Team     Date Score mean.score sd.score
## 1:    A 1-1-2012    80         65 23.80476
## 2:    A 1-2-2012    90         65 23.80476
## 3:    A 1-3-2012    50         65 23.80476
## 4:    A 1-4-2012    40         65 23.80476
## 5:    B 1-1-2012   100         65 28.86751
## 6:    B 1-2-2012    60         65 28.86751
## 7:    B 1-3-2012    30         65 28.86751
## 8:    B 1-4-2012    70         65 28.86751
DT[, outlier := abs(Score-mean.score) > 3 * sd.score, by = Team]
##    Team     Date Score mean.score sd.score outlier
## 1:    A 1-1-2012    80         65 23.80476   FALSE
## 2:    A 1-2-2012    90         65 23.80476   FALSE
## 3:    A 1-3-2012    50         65 23.80476   FALSE
## 4:    A 1-4-2012    40         65 23.80476   FALSE
## 5:    B 1-1-2012   100         65 28.86751   FALSE
## 6:    B 1-2-2012    60         65 28.86751   FALSE
## 7:    B 1-3-2012    30         65 28.86751   FALSE
## 8:    B 1-4-2012    70         65 28.86751   FALSE
```

Or, in a single step

```
DT[, outlier := abs(Score-mean(Score)) > 3 *  sd(Score), by = Team]
```

To add the number of outliers (sum on a  logical variable will coerce to 0,1)

```
DT[, sum.outlier := sum(outlier), by = Team]
```

Comment: thank you so much. I will try this first thing tomorrow morning. I think this will work. Rather than having true false, I can give it an integer and than pefrom aggregate(outlier~Team, sum, DT) and get the sum values for each team and then graph top ten.

Comment: @user - for most purposes, R will treat TRUE/FALSE as 1/0 respectively.

Comment: @mnel, I performend this and it is performing at phenomanol rate better than plyr.

Comment: @mnel, I have a question. Rather than looking at the abs, I am only interested in positive values of this calculations: outlier := abs(Score-mean(Score)) > 3 *  sd(Score), by=Team. is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I would leave your data in long format and use `plyr`, `data.table`, or any of the other split-apply-combine tools to compute your statistics. Here's how I'd use `plyr` for the task:

```
#Your data
dat <- read.table(text = "Team Date       Score
A    1-1-2012   80
A    1-2-2012   90
A    1-3-2012   50
A    1-4-2012   40   
B    1-1-2012   100
B    1-2-2012   60
B    1-3-2012   30
B    1-4-2012   70", header = TRUE)

library(plyr)

#Compute mean and sd by team
dat <- ddply(dat, .(Team), transform, mean = mean(Score), sd = sd(Score))
#Your outlier threshold
dat <- transform(dat, outlier = abs(Score - mean) > 3*sd)
#Cumulative sum by team
dat <- ddply(dat, .(Team), transform, cumsumOutlier = cumsum(outlier))
```

Gives you this as an output (which does not match your example, but presumably your real data does):

```
 Team     Date Score mean       sd outlier cumsumOutlier
1    A 1-1-2012    80   65 23.80476   FALSE             0
2    A 1-2-2012    90   65 23.80476   FALSE             0
3    A 1-3-2012    50   65 23.80476   FALSE             0
4    A 1-4-2012    40   65 23.80476   FALSE             0
5    B 1-1-2012   100   65 28.86751   FALSE             0
6    B 1-2-2012    60   65 28.86751   FALSE             0
7    B 1-3-2012    30   65 28.86751   FALSE             0
8    B 1-4-2012    70   65 28.86751   FALSE             0
```

Comment: cue someone coming along with some timing results...`data.table` will win that fight, here's some [proof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748253/idiomatic-r-code-for-partitioning-a-vector-by-an-index-and-performing-an-operati/10748470#10748470)

Comment: I'm curious as to how you would use the cumsumOutlier column.  I'm guessing it keeps a running tally of the number of outliers found in each team.  How would you put that information to use in a practical sense?