# Function to remove Outliers from a DataFrame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, outliers

I want to write a function that will take a `data.frame` as input and return a new `data.frame` that has replaced outliers using the `tsclean()` function from the forecast package.

For the example input `df` (containing obvious outliers):

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = runif(24, 400, 700),
                 col2 = runif(24, 350, 600),
                 col3 = runif(24, 600, 940),
                 col4 = runif(24, 2000, 2600),
                 col5 = runif(24, 950, 1200))

colnames(df) <- c("2to2", "2to6", "17to9", "20to31", "90to90")
df$`2to2`[[12]]=10000
df$`17to9`[[20]]=6000
df$`20to31`[[8]]=12000
```

I've been trying to solve this as follows

```
clean_ts <- function(df, frequency = 12, start = c(2014, 1), end = c(2015, 12)) {

  ts <- ts(df, frequency = frequency, start = start, end = end)
  results <- list()

  for (i in 1:ncol(ts)) {
    clean <- as.data.frame(tsclean(ts[,i]))
    results[[i]] <- as.data.frame(cbind(clean))
  }
  return(results)
}
```

I know this is wrong. Instead of returning a list I want my function to return a `data.frame` with the same dimensions and column names as my input `data.frame`. I just want the columns of the `data.frame()` replaced according to the `tsclean()` function. So from the example my output would have the following form:

```
2to2  2to6  17to9  20to31  90to90
 .     .     .       .       .
 .     .     .       .       .
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866189/calculating-the-outliers-in-r

This may be of some use for you as well.

Idea being is you create a function that intakes a dataframe, summarizes the dataframe by the finding the quantiles, upper and lower thresholds and filter the final dataset outside that range..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to make every column a data frame when assigning it to the list. This is unnecessary. We can also avoid the initialize-to-list-and-cbind workflow by just overwriting the columns in the `df` object one at a time.

```
clean_ts <- function(df, frequency = 12, start = c(2014, 1), end = c(2015, 12)) {

  ts <- ts(df, frequency = frequency, start = start, end = end)

  for (i in 1:ncol(ts)) {
    df[, i] <- tsclean(ts[, i])
   }
  return(df)
}
```

Even cleaner, we can use `lapply` to hide the loop:

```
clean_ts <- function(df, frequency = 12, start = c(2014, 1), end = c(2015, 12)) {
  ts <- ts(df, frequency = frequency, start = start, end = end)
  return(as.data.frame(lapply, ts, tsclean)))
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!