# Write a function to loop through each column and flag the outlier in R

Tags: r, function, loops, flags

I am new to writing function in R, I have a dataset(created by me for practice from a large dataset), I want to loop through each column and flag the outlier.Any help or advice is appreciable!
This is my dataset:

```
               Time Temperature.C. Relative_Humidity
1  10/24/2022 16:45           32.2              50.0
2  10/24/2022 16:46           30.0              49.0
3  10/24/2022 16:47           31.0              50.0
4  10/24/2022 16:48           30.0              50.5
5  10/24/2022 16:49           30.0              50.0
6  10/24/2022 16:50           31.0              49.0
7  10/24/2022 16:51           32.2              51.0
8  10/24/2022 16:52           86.0              50.5
9  10/24/2022 16:53           30.0              50.0
10 10/24/2022 16:54           30.0             120.0
11 10/24/2022 16:55           30.0              50.0
12 10/24/2022 16:56           86.0              50.0
13 10/24/2022 16:57           30.0              51.0
14 10/24/2022 16:58           31.0              51.0
15 10/24/2022 16:59           31.0              50.0
16 10/24/2022 17:00           31.0              49.0
17 10/24/2022 17:01            3.0              52.0
18 10/24/2022 17:02           32.2              49.0
19 10/24/2022 17:03           30.0               2.0

structure(list(Time = c("10/24/2022 16:45", "10/24/2022 16:46", 
"10/24/2022 16:47", "10/24/2022 16:48", "10/24/2022 16:49", "10/24/2022 16:50", 
"10/24/2022 16:51", "10/24/2022 16:52", "10/24/2022 16:53", "10/24/2022 16:54", 
"10/24/2022 16:55", "10/24/2022 16:56", "10/24/2022 16:57", "10/24/2022 16:58", 
"10/24/2022 16:59", "10/24/2022 17:00", "10/24/2022 17:01", "10/24/2022 17:02", 
"10/24/2022 17:03"), Temperature.C. = c(32.2, 30, 31, 30, 30, 
31, 32.2, 86, 30, 30, 30, 86, 30, 31, 31, 31, 3, 32.2, 30), Relative_Humidity = c(50, 
49, 50, 50.5, 50, 49, 51, 50.5, 50, 120, 50, 50, 51, 51, 50, 
49, 52, 49, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L
))
```

I am expecting my output like this.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

**Update. see OP comment:**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Flag_temp = ifelse(Temperature.C. >= 30 & Temperature.C. <= 32, "", "FLAG"),
         Flag_RelHumidity = ifelse(Relative_Humidity >= 49 & Relative_Humidity <= 50, "", "FLAG"))
```

**First answer:**
Define your outlier limits [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985016/flagging-the-outliers-in-a-dataset-in-r-with-additional-column):

You probably want to define an outlier as

1. data point above Q3 + IQR * 1.5
2. data point under 5 percentile + IQR * 1.5

These conditions fit best to your provided example:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-Time, ~case_when(. > quantile(., probs = 0.75) + IQR(.) * 1.5 ~ "FLAG", 
                                  . < quantile(., probs = 0.05) + IQR(.) * 1.5 ~ "FLAG",
                                  TRUE ~ ""), .names = "{col}_outlier")) %>% 
  relocate(Time, starts_with("Temperature"))
```

```
               Time Temperature.C. Temperature.C._outlier Relative_Humidity Relative_Humidity_outlier
1  10/24/2022 16:45           32.2                                     50.0                          
2  10/24/2022 16:46           30.0                                     49.0                          
3  10/24/2022 16:47           31.0                                     50.0                          
4  10/24/2022 16:48           30.0                                     50.5                          
5  10/24/2022 16:49           30.0                                     50.0                          
6  10/24/2022 16:50           31.0                                     49.0                          
7  10/24/2022 16:51           32.2                                     51.0                          
8  10/24/2022 16:52           86.0                   FLAG              50.5                          
9  10/24/2022 16:53           30.0                                     50.0                          
10 10/24/2022 16:54           30.0                                    120.0                      FLAG
11 10/24/2022 16:55           30.0                                     50.0                          
12 10/24/2022 16:56           86.0                   FLAG              50.0                          
13 10/24/2022 16:57           30.0                                     51.0                          
14 10/24/2022 16:58           31.0                                     51.0                          
15 10/24/2022 16:59           31.0                                     50.0                          
16 10/24/2022 17:00           31.0                                     49.0                          
17 10/24/2022 17:01            3.0                   FLAG              52.0                          
18 10/24/2022 17:02           32.2                                     49.0                          
19 10/24/2022 17:03           30.0                                      2.0                      FLAG
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I do have a question, what if I want to set my own limit? for example: what if the temperature limit is between 30 & 32 and the relative humidity limit is 49 to 50, and the rest will be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

This tidyverse example may be useful:

##### 1. Create a sample dataset

```
library(tidyverse) 

sample_data <- data.frame(
  a = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE),
  b = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE),
  c = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE),
  d = sample(1:10, 10, TRUE)
)
```

##### 2. Detect which value(s) are outliers

Based on your description, it seems outliers are the maximum and minimum values, so we can use the `range()` function to get the range of each column.

```
outcome <- sample_data |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(    # note 1
    .x == range(.x) ~ "Flag",                 # note 2
    TRUE ~ ""
  )))
```

note 1: You may need to replace `everything()` to `c(var1, var2 ...)` based on your dataset.
note 2: This part marks outliers as "Flag", and marks the rest as "".

##### 3. Rename the outcome columns:

```
names(outcome) <- paste0(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), "_flag")
```

##### 4. Combine data and outcome as one dataset

```
outcome <- bind_cols(sample_data, outcome)
```

##### 5. Reorder the columns alphabetically

```
outcome <- outcome |> 
  select(order(colnames(outcome)))
```

The final outcome should look like below after you run `outcome`:

```
    a a_flag b b_flag  c c_flag d d_flag
1  10        1   Flag 10        7       
2   5        9   Flag  5        8   Flag
3   1   Flag 8         6        5       
4   7        3         7        8   Flag
5   3        7         8        4       
6   4        2         7        4       
7   6        5         7        5       
8   2        4         5        5       
9   1   Flag 2         2   Flag 5       
10 10   Flag 5        10   Flag 1
```

Hope this example is helpful for your case.

#### Update ------------------------------------------------------------------

2022.12.27

##### 1. Repeat step 1

Create sample data to work with.

##### 2. Customised values to flag

```
outcome <- sample_data |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(    
    (.x >=1 & .x <= 2)  ~ "Flag",      # Define the lower range
    (.x >=9 & .x <= 10)  ~ "Flag",     # Define the upper range
    TRUE ~ ""
  )))
```

##### 3. Repeat step 3, 4, 5

```
names(outcome) <- paste0(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), "_flag")

outcome <- bind_cols(sample_data, outcome)

outcome <- outcome |> 
  select(order(colnames(outcome)))
```

The Customised final outcome should look like below after you run `outcome`:

```
   a a_flag  b b_flag  c c_flag d d_flag
   5         4         4        7       
   6         9   Flag  5        7       
   1   Flag 10   Flag  3        4       
   3         5         4        6       
  10   Flag  4         9   Flag 2   Flag
   4         9   Flag  5        1   Flag
   1   Flag  1   Flag  5        7       
   1   Flag  8        10   Flag 5       
   2   Flag  2   Flag 10   Flag 3       
   2   Flag  9   Flag  3        1   Flag
```

Comment: However, I do have a question. What if I wish to choose my own limit? the rest will be flag, for instance, if the temperature limit is between 30 and 32 and the relative humidity limit is 49 to 50.

Comment: It's doable - please see the updated post above - hope it is helpful.