# In lattice histogram how to keep only 99% of the data?

Tags: r, histogram, lattice, percentile

In my lattice histogram:

```
histogram(~bill|group,data=mydat,type='count',nint=50,layout=c(9,3))
```

How to keep "bill" data before 99th percentile within each group?

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you mean by "keep"?

Comment: If the data are very skewed, you could add `scales = list(x = list(log = 2))` to the arguments for `histogram` as a potential alternative to eliminating data.

Comment: @joran  Keep is to keep, others (1% at the end) will be trimmed.

Comment: Do you want to remove outliers from all the bill data or within each group?

Comment: @BenBarnes I don't necessary need log transformation at this stage; the data has outliners that unanimously present at the 1% end while 99% others show normal distribution.

Comment: @Seth  Yes! And I already know that all these outliners (within each group) are at the top 1% --that's why I want to take them off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to remove outliers from the whole of the bill data. First copy your data into a new variable

```
    mydat$bill.cleaned=mydat$bill
```

then set the large values to missing

```
    cuttoff= qnorm(.99,mean(mydat$bill),sd(mydat$bill))
    mydat$bill.cleaned[which(mydat$bill > cuttoff)]=NA
```

Then you can display your histogram of cleaned data.

Alternatively if you want to remove ouliers only within each group. you need to do the same thing as above with an additional apply statement.

Comment: Thank you @Seth! I later also find a similar solution like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4788102/2078985

Comment: How to "do the same thing as above with an additional apply statement" ? I searched for a while but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I got the problem solved using ave (learnt from another post). Thanks!