# How exactly are outliers removed in R boxplot and how can the same outliers be removed for further calculation (e.g. mean)?

Tags: r, mean, outliers

In a `boxplot` I've set the option `outline=FALSE` to remove the outliers.
Now I'd like to include `points` that show the **mean** in the boxplot. Obviously, the means calculated using `mean` include the outliers.

How can the very same outliers be removed from a dataframe so that the calculated mean corresponds to the data shown in the boxplot?

I know how outliers can be removed, but which settings are used by the `outline` option from `boxplot` internally? Unfortunately, the manual does not give any clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the outliers, you must set the option `outline` to `FALSE`.

Let's assume that your data are the following:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(seq(0,1,0.1),3))
```

Then, you use the `boxplot` function:

```
res <- boxplot(data, outline=FALSE)
```

In the `res` object, you have several pieces of information about your data. Among these, `res$out` gives you all the outliers. Here there is only the value 3.

Thus, to compute the mean without the outliers, you can simply do:

```
mean(data$a[!data$a %in% res$out])
```

Answer (score 7):

To answer the second part of your question, about how the outliers are choosen, it's good to remind how the boxplot is constructed:

- the "body" of the boxplot corresponds to the second + third quartiles of the data (= interquartile range, IQR)
- each whisker limit is generally calculated taking 1.5*IQR beyond the end of that body.

If you take the hypothesis that your data has a normal distribution, there are this amount of data outside each whisker:

```
1-pnorm(qnorm(0.75)+1.5*2*qnorm(0.75))
```

being 0.0035. Therefore, a normal variable has 0.7% of "boxplot outliers".

But this is not a very "reliable" way to detect outliers, there are [packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/outliers.pdf) specifically designed for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating on the procedure of outlier removal. This really rounds up the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the **Value** section of `?boxplot`, you find:

"List with the following components:"
[...]

`out` the values of any data points which lie beyond the extremes of the whiskers."

Thus, you can assing the result of your `boxplot` call to an object, extract the outliers, and remove them from the original values:

```
x <- c(-10, 1:5, 50)
x
# [1] -10   1   2   3   4   5  50

bx <- boxplot(x)
str(bx)
# List of 6
# $ stats: num [1:5, 1] 1 1.5 3 4.5 5
# $ n    : num 7
# $ conf : num [1:2, 1] 1.21 4.79
# $ out  : num [1:2] -10 50
# $ group: num [1:2] 1 1
# $ names: chr "1"

x2 <- x[!(x %in% bx$out)]
x2
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787332/how-to-remove-outliers-from-a-dataset/4937343#4937343