# Is there an inbuilt function to identify outliers in all columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r

Do we have inbuilt function in R which can be used to identify outliers in each column of the data frame?
I am working on a logistic regression problem that has some 100 columns.
Could anybody help recommend a function?

Comment: You can start by using the code available here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089894/identifying-the-outliers-in-a-data-set-in-r/44089981 . If you get stuck update your post with an example dataset, expected output, code that you tried and the place where you get stuck.

Comment: There is no formal, universally agreed definition of "outlier". In order to know what's an outlier, you need to know about the population you are studying and need to consider what modeling assumptions you are making to study them.