# Complex dataframe selecting and sorting by quintile

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a complex dataframe (orig_df).  Of the 25 columns, 5 are descriptions and characteristics that I wish to use as grouping criteria.  The remainder are time series.  There are tens of thousands of rows.

I noted in initial analysis and numerical summary that there are significant issues with outlier observations within some of the specific grouping criteria. I used "group by" and looking at the quintile results within those groups. I would like to eliminate the low and high (individual observation) outliers relative to the (group-by based quintile) to improve the decision tree and clustering analytics.  I also want to keep the outliers to analyze separately for the root cause.

How do I manipulate the dataframe such that the individual observations are compared to the group-based quintile results and the parse is saved (orig_df becomes ideal_df and outlier_df)?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787332/how-to-remove-outliers-from-a-dataset

Answer (score 0):

After identifying the outliers using the link Nikos Tavoularis share above, you can use `ifelse` to create a new variable and identify which records are outliers and the ones that are not. This way you can keep the data there, but you can use this new variable to sort them out whenever you want