# Trimmed mean by group in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, weighted-average

I have a data.table on which I want to find the weighted mean of column `performance` by month.

```
  dat <- structure(list(year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
                                 2021, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), 
                        month = c(2, 
                                  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
                        performance = c(0.826973794097158, 
                                        0.61975709469356, 0.924350659523548, -0.183133219063708, -0.529913189565746, 
                                        -0.148531188902535, -0.0773058814083695, 1.42862504650241, 0.465498268732376, 
                                        0.148719963224136, 0.205614191281359, 0.560651497949418, -0.484408605607923, 
                                        0.875353374774486, 0.351469397380814)), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

This data.table looks like following -

```
    year month performance
 1: 2014     2  0.82697379
 2: 2015     2  0.61975709
 3: 2016     2  0.92435066
 4: 2017     2 -0.18313322
 5: 2018     2 -0.52991319
 6: 2019     2 -0.14853119
 7: 2020     2 -0.07730588
 8: 2021     2  1.42862505
 9: 2014    10  0.46549827
10: 2015    10  0.14871996
11: 2016    10  0.20561419
12: 2017    10  0.56065150
13: 2018    10 -0.48440861
14: 2019    10  0.87535337
15: 2020    10  0.35146940
```

To find the weighted mean by month, I have used the following code -

```
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(month), .SDcols = c("performance")]
```

and the result I am getting is -

```
   month performance
1:     2   0.3576029
2:    10   0.3032712
```

However, the weighted mean performance of month `10` should be greater than month `2` as it has more positive values.

It seems that only the month `2` of the year 2021, is weighing heavily on its performance causing it to outperform the performance of month `10`.
Actually, the code above is only finding the `mean` and NOT the `weighted.mean`. The result is the same if I use `mean` instead of `weighted.mean`.

```
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(month), .SDcols = c("performance")]
```

and the result after using simple mean is following, which is the same as the result of weighted.mean.

```
   month performance
1:     2   0.3576029
2:    10   0.3032712
```

The desired result should give equal weight to the performance of each year so that exceptional performance in one particular year does not falsely show that the product sells wonderfully during that month each year.

Can someone point out what is wrong with my weighted mean calculation?

Comment: What do you call weighted mean? in R this means `?weighted.mean`, and as you don't give any weight, you get a normal mean.

Comment: In the reference section of package stats, it is mentioned for ```weighted.mean``` - "If w is missing then all elements of x are given the same weight." I want to keep the weights for each year equal.

Comment: So you get a normal mean : what is the problem then?

Comment: If each year has equal weight, then the performance of month ```10``` should be better than month ```2```. See all the negative values in month ```2```. I have tried to explain it little better in question. If we find mean of sign of ```performance``` column, then month ```10``` is the clear winner. ```setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(sign(x), na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(month), .SDcols = c("performance")]
```

Comment: no, because `mean=sum/n` and as you pointed out row 8 compensates all the negative values. Are you looking for median?

Comment: Using the ```median``` gives a better result than ```mean``` but that does not solve the problem. I want to assign equal weight to the performance for each month so that it does not dominate the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply [remove outliers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788102/13513328) :

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  y
}
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(remove_outliers(x))), by = .(month), .SDcols = c("performance")]

month performance
1:     2   0.3576029
2:    10   0.4345511
```

Or limit outliers, for instance to first and third quartile:

```
limit_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] )] <- qnt[1]
  y[x > (qnt[2] )] <- qnt[2] 
  y
}

setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(limit_outliers(x), na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(month), .SDcols = c("performance")]

month performance
1:     2   0.3261458
2:    10   0.3432951
```

Comment: Removing the outliers is not giving the best results on the complete dataset. Is it possible to limit the max a year that can affect the end result? e.g. on line 8 of dataset ``` 8: 2021     2  1.42862505``` the max performance is 1.42 and I want to consider it no more than 1 (100%).

Answer (score 1):

As a new stackoverflow user I can not add commnets on post, so I will add my doubts here.

In general you are getting a simple mean with the code you porvide, and i do not understand clearly what your want, because normally when you want a weighted mean, you use a second variable as weight.

In your case, a simple mean return the same output:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(performance = mean(performance))
```

Comment: In the reference section of package ```stats```, it is mentioned for ```weighted.mean``` - "If w is missing then all elements of x are given the same weight." I want to keep the weights for each year equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you use weighted.mean function without specifying the weights it will simply calculate an average for you. To calculate it correctly you can specify your weights as second parameter in your weighted.mean function.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- structure(list(year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
                               2021, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), 
                      month = c(2, 
                                2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
                      performance = c(0.826973794097158, 
                                      0.61975709469356, 0.924350659523548, -0.183133219063708, -0.529913189565746, 
                                      -0.148531188902535, -0.0773058814083695, 1.42862504650241, 0.465498268732376, 
                                      0.148719963224136, 0.205614191281359, 0.560651497949418, -0.484408605607923, 
                                      0.875353374774486, 0.351469397380814)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
head(dat)
setDT(dat)
dat[,.(weighted.mean(performance)), by = month]
dat[,.(mean(performance)), by = month]
```

R execution

[image]

So to resolve this issue you can do the following :
add a column of weights into your dataset. I added wt variable as my weights. Here I just simply took a sequence 1 to 15 as my weights, you need to put exact values/weights in place of this. Then just add this parameter as argument in your weighted.mean function, I think this should resolve your problem.

```
dat$wt <- 1:nrow(dat)
weighted.mean(dat$performance,dat$wt) # will give you full column weighted mean
dat[,.(weighted.mean(performance,wt)), by = .(month)] # will give you weighted mean by month
```

R result :

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the problem I am facing. Both ```mean``` and ```weighted.mean``` gives the same result.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I have added some more information to my answer on how you can add weights. Please check, and let me know in case of you still have doubts & if this is what your looking for.

Comment: As you have used the incremental weights, doing so will increase the impact of recent years over the past years. This is not what I am looking for. I want to limit the max impact of a year's performance so that it does not artificially increase the performance for any month.

Comment: My weights are just for your example.. you can use it as per your convenience. If you does not want to emphasize on any specific year using weighted mean is meaningless, as this is what for its made of. I recommend you to use some other measure like trimmed mean or median instead, this will do your work no need to go for weighted mean.

Comment: Thanks, Arup, Waldi has shared a kind of trimmed mean procedure while limiting the effects of extreme values.